# hibernate Mapping error with id

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, thymeleaf

I am new to spring MVC and JPA, hibernate. I am stuck with this error. I want your help friends in my project we are using spring MVC, hibernate, JPA, thymeleaf.
I am implementing questioner form this is my database script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assessments`(   
`assessment_id`  bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`assessment_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
`start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
`end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`assessment_id`)  
);  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions`(  
`question_id`  bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`question` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
`assessment_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
 PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`),  
 KEY `fk_key1` (`assessment_id`),  
 CONSTRAINT `fk_key1` FOREIGN KEY (`assessment_id`) REFERENCES`assessments`(`assessment_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answers` (  
`answer_id`  bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`answer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
`question_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`answer_id`),  
  KEY `fk_key2` (`question_id`),  
 CONSTRAINT `fk_key2` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `questions` (`question_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION );
```

and my model layer class

```
public class Assessments {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "assessmentGen", sequenceName = "assessment_generator")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "assessmentGen")   
private long assessmentId;

@Column    
private String assessmentName;

@Column    
private Date startDate;

@Column   
private Date endDate;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "assessmentId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)   
private List<Questions> questions = new ArrayList<Questions>();}
```

---

```
public class Questions {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "questionGen", sequenceName = "question_generator")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "questionGen")  
private long questionId;

@Column    
private String question;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "questionId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)    
private List<Answers> answers = new ArrayList<Answers>();

@ManyToOne(optional = false)    
private Assessments assessmentId;

}
```

---

```
public class Answers {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "answersGen", sequenceName = "answers_generator")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "answersGen")   
private long answerId;

@Column(name = "answer")   
private String answer;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Questions questionId;
}
```

---

and my page in thymeleaf

```
<form name="assessmentform" id="assessmentform" method="post"
                th:action="@{/saveassessment}" th:object="${assessments}"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div id="sf1" class="frm">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Assessment</legend>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="assessment">Assessment
                                Name: </label>
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="assessmentName"
                                    th:field="*{assessmentName}" class="form-control"
                                    autocomplete="off" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="startDate">Start
                                Date: </label>
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <input type="text" id="startDate" th:field="*{startDate}"
                                    class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="endDate">End
                                Date: </label>
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <input type="text" id="endDate" th:field="*{endDate}"
                                    class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
                        <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary " type="button" id="addquestion"
                                    name="addquestion">Add New Question</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-warning " type="button" id="remove"
                                    name="remove">Remove Question</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="templateWrapper">
                            <div class="questiontemplate">
                                <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="question">Question
                                    1: </label>
                                <textarea id="question" th:field="*{questions[0].question}"
                                    cols="47" rows="3"></textarea><div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="question">Option
                                    1: </label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="option 1" id="option1" th:field="*{questions[0].answers[0].answer}" 
                                     autocomplete="off" size="50" /><div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="question">Option
                                    2: </label>      
                                <input type="text" placeholder="option 2" id="option2" th:field="*{questions[0].answers[1].answer}" 
                                     autocomplete="off" size="50" /><div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="question">Option
                                    3: </label>   
                                <input type="text" placeholder="option 3" id="option3" th:field="*{questions[0].answers[2].answer}" 
                                     autocomplete="off" size="50" /><div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div> 
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="question">Option
                                    4: </label>  
                                <input type="text" placeholder="option 4" id="option4" th:field="*{questions[0].answers[3].answer}" 
                                     autocomplete="off" size="50" /><div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
                                <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix" style="height: 10px; clear: both;"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary open2" type="submit">Submit
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </form>
```

---

and this my controller

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/saveassessment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveassessmentForm(@ModelAttribute("Assessment") Assessments assessments, BindingResult assresult) {
    try {
        assessmentsService.saveAssessments(assessments);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return "public_index";
}
```

When I am trying to save the data into database it's saving the data but it's not showing the relation I mean assessmentId column in questions table is showing null instead of assessmentid of assessment table and same to the questionId column of answers table is null. I think I am missing something which I am able to find.
               i hope i am clear with my error

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Otherwise it's a lot of code for people to review without any leads

Comment: i am not getting any error it's saving to the database the only thing is i am not able to save questions with id of assessment

Answer (score 0):

You did not post all the relevant code so I'll guess.

In bidirectional associations, like you have between Assessment and Questions and between Questions and Answers you have to set both sides of the associations. I mean, if an association is bidirectional, you have to create the link with pointers on two sides, not just one.

So, in your Assessments class you may have a convenience method to help you do this:

```
public class Assessments {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "assessmentId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)   
    private List<Questions> questions = new ArrayList<Questions>();}
    ...

    public void addQuestion(Questions question) {
        question.setAssessmentId(this);
        questions.add(question);
    }

}
```

Than, in your DAO, you have to save() both objects:

```
Assessments assessments = new Assessments();
Questions question = new Question();

assessments.addQuestion(question); // Set both sides of the association

...

session.save(assessments);
session.save(question);
```

You have to call save() twice because both classes are entities and their instances have a completely independent lifecycle. New objects are transient and have to be made persistent if you want to store them in the database. Their relationship doesn't influence their lifecycle, if they're entities.

Comment: The first part of your answer is correct however wouldn't specifying the cascade option be a better solution than saving assessments and question independently.

Comment: can u help me out how to get assessment id of that assessment which database is genrating. how to bring it to the controller

Comment: @AlanHay you're right. Specifying the cascade option would be better to avoid calling save() twice. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @kiran when you call 'save(assessment)' hibernate will set the generated id in the same assessment instance. So you should be able to access the id using 'assessment.getAssessmentId();'

Comment: @A.Baldo after doing what u suggested now it's not even saving questions.later it used to save then questions without assessment id .can check the  forntedn page code  once i think problem is in there..